# How can I get my J query slider to work?

Tags: jquery

I would greatly appreciate any help in getting this to work. I have tried a few of these Jquery slider tutorials but I guess I must keep missing something crucial?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>ssss</title>
<meta name="generator" content="BBEdit 10.5" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="responsiveslides.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".responsiveslides").responsiveSlides();
  });
</script>

<script>
$(".responsiveslides").responsiveSlides({
  auto: true,             // Boolean: Animate automatically, true or false
  speed: 50,            // Integer: Speed of the transition, in milliseconds
  timeout: 4000,          // Integer: Time between slide transitions, in milliseconds
  pager: true,           // Boolean: Show pager, true or false
  nav: true,             // Boolean: Show navigation, true or false
  random: true,          // Boolean: Randomize the order of the slides, true or false
  pause: true,           // Boolean: Pause on hover, true or false
  pauseControls: true,    // Boolean: Pause when hovering controls, true or false
  prevText: "Previous",   // String: Text for the "previous" button
  nextText: "Next",       // String: Text for the "next" button
  maxwidth: "",           // Integer: Max-width of the slideshow, in pixels
  navContainer: "default",       // Selector: Where controls should be appended to, default is after the 'ul'
  manualControls: "",     // Selector: Declare custom pager navigation
  namespace: "rslides",   // String: Change the default namespace used
  before: function(){},   // Function: Before callback
  after: function(){}     // Function: After callback
});

</script>
    <style>

.responsiveslides {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }

.responsiveslides li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  }

.responsiveslides li:first-child {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  }

.responsiveslides img {
  display: block;
  height: 60%;
  float: left;
  width: 69%;
  border: 0;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="responsiveslides">
    <li><img src="/Users/mitchellheritagehaldenby/Desktop/outcast%20website/images/image%201.jpg"  alt="101"/> </li>
    <li><img src="/Users/mitchellheritagehaldenby/Desktop/outcast%20website/images/image%202.jpg"  alt="101"/></li>
    <li><img src="/Users/mitchellheritagehaldenby/Desktop/outcast%20website/images/image%203.jpg"  alt="101"/></li>
    <li><img src="/Users/mitchellheritagehaldenby/Desktop/outcast%20website/images/image%204.jpg"  alt="101"/></li>
    <li><img src="/Users/mitchellheritagehaldenby/Desktop/outcast%20website/images/image%205.jpg"  alt="101"/></li>
    <li><img src="/Users/mitchellheritagehaldenby/Desktop/outcast%20website/images/image%206.jpg"  alt="101"/></li>
    <li><img src="/Users/mitchellheritagehaldenby/Desktop/outcast%20website/images/image%207.jpg"  alt="101"/></li>
    <li><img src="/Users/mitchellheritagehaldenby/Desktop/outcast%20website/images/image%208.jpg"  alt="101"/></li>
    <li><img src="/Users/mitchellheritagehaldenby/Desktop/outcast%20website/images/image%209.jpg"  alt="101"/></li>
    <li><img src="/Users/mitchellheritagehaldenby/Desktop/outcast%20website/images/image%2010.jpg"  alt="101"/></li>
    <li><img src="/Users/mitchellheritagehaldenby/Desktop/outcast%20website/images/image%2011.jpg"  alt="101"/></li>
    <li><img src="/Users/mitchellheritagehaldenby/Desktop/outcast%20website/images/image%2012.jpg"  alt="101"/></li>
    <li><img src="/Users/mitchellheritagehaldenby/Desktop/outcast%20website/images/image%2013.jpg"  alt="101"/></li>
    <li><img src="/Users/mitchellheritagehaldenby/Desktop/outcast%20website/images/image%2014.jpg"  alt="101"/></li>
    <li><img src="/Users/mitchellheritagehaldenby/Desktop/outcast%20website/images/image%2015.jpg"  alt="101"/></li>
    <li><img src="/Users/mitchellheritagehaldenby/Desktop/outcast%20website/images/image%2016.jpg"  alt="101"/></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you actually download the plugin and put it in the same folder on your server as this page? Are all the urls for images correct?

Comment: Why are you initializing `responsiveSlides` twice?

Comment: Hello thank you for a swift reply.. I have added the slider file in a folder i called js inside my main folder in which my html barebones are kept.All images are the same size and function perfectly as I have tried them with a non responsive older query slider and it works. But not the slider I want. the link to the slider I downloaded ishttps://github.com/viljamis/ResponsiveSlides.js

Comment: I didn't realise I had initiated it twice so I have removed the duplicate but still no response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont need to include the arguments unless you want to change the defaults. Here's mine. Its the only script on the page

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
        nav:true,
    });
  });
</script>
```

All I want to do is show the nav. The rest stay default. Im using jquery 1.11.0

Heres the links to my scripts in my header

```
<script src="incls/jq1110.js"></script>
<script src="incls/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
```

Also you say the responsiveslides file is in a folder called js. From your script tag below you look to be calling it from the same directory as your webpage

```
<script src="responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
```

should it be 
`<script src="js/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>`?

cheers

Comment: Do you know how I would go about adding the nab buttons ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're initializing the plugin twice.

First here, with no options...

```
$(function() {
    $(".responsiveslides").responsiveSlides();
});
```

And secondly here with a whole slew of them...

```
$(".responsiveslides").responsiveSlides({
    auto: true,              // Boolean: Animate automatically, true or false
    speed: 50,               // Integer: Speed of the transition, in milliseconds
    timeout: 4000,           // Integer: Time between slide transitions, in milliseconds
    pager: true,             // Boolean: Show pager, true or false
    nav: true,               // Boolean: Show navigation, true or false
    random: true,            // Boolean: Randomize the order of the slides, true or false
    pause: true,             // Boolean: Pause on hover, true or false
    pauseControls: true,     // Boolean: Pause when hovering controls, true or false
    prevText: "Previous",    // String: Text for the "previous" button
    nextText: "Next",        // String: Text for the "next" button
    maxwidth: "",            // Integer: Max-width of the slideshow, in pixels
    navContainer: "default", // Selector: Where controls should be appended to, default is after the 'ul'
    manualControls: "",      // Selector: Declare custom pager navigation
    namespace: "rslides",    // String: Change the default namespace used
    before: function() {},   // Function: Before callback
    after: function() {}     // Function: After callback
});
```

You only need to initialize the plugin once. Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/galengidman/JqU77/

Comment: Hi so I removed the duplicate code, but still not working ?? I don't know if this should make any difference but it is not on a server yet as I'm still constructing it and secondly does it matter if the downloaded file is in a separate file inside the main file of my Barebones code?